# Evaluating the inverse Laplace transform of $1/(s^2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty{n!s^{3-n}x^n})$

Tags: generating-functions, laplace-transform, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I want to evaluate at $t=1$ the inverse Laplace Transform $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}\vert_{t=1}$ of

$$
 F(s) = \frac{1}{s^2-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{n!s^{3-n}x^n}}
$$

and find out the $x^n$ coefficient $[x^n]\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}\vert_{t=1}$ of this evaluation.

If I approximate the sum to $m$ terms I can use *Mathematica* to calculate the coefficients of $x^n$ to be $1, 1, 2, 4, 23/3, 14,\ldots$.

However, I am after an analytic expression for  $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}\vert_{t=1}$ or  $[x^n]\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}\vert_{t=1}$.

Is this feasible?

Comment: That series is divergent.

Comment: Even though the series diverges, would it be possible to come up with an analytic expression for the coefficient of $x^n$?

Comment: You have $n!s^{3-n}$.  That is the coefficient on $x^n$, is it not?

Comment: Stirling's formula for $n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n +O(1/n)$.

Comment: I meant $[x^n]\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}\vert_{t=1}=1, 1, 2, 4, 23/3, 14, 733/30,\ldots$.